# Google-like search (with several keywords) in local (project) files

Tags: search, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-matching

Is there a minor-mode/function that let me search through a project with several keywords, in the way I a search for files on google. The result should be, like in search engines on the web, a list of files with the most relevant result at the top.

Comment: I once started working on a project that used Sphinx (full-text search engine for databases like MySQL), that would do this kind of thing. I didn't finish it though... But, technically, the problem with what you are asking for is that whatever *will* do this search will also have to constantly reindex the contents of the directories you search, which, obviously, takes a lot of resources. Linux desktops typically come with programs that do indexing of file contents, but, also, typically they would be the first to be disabled due to decreased performance.

Comment: In OSX, y customized `locate-command` to `mdfind`, which is the CLI interface to spotlight search. You should be able to use the file-indexing command for your platform.